# Setting default textInput value in R shiny via js (as result of js function)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to use R shiny app with js SDK of one social network. I want to get user id from js API and set it as default value for textInput form. 
But only once, for the first time.

The best result I managed to achieve using `Shiny.onInputChange()` function (or `Shiny.setInputValue()` for shiny>1.1)

Toy example:

```py
ui <- fluidPage(

 textInput("uid",label = h4("Input ID"),value = "1"),
 actionButton("goButton", "Check this out!", class="btn-primary"),

 # getting user id via js
 tags$script(HTML(
  '
  uid = some_js_code;
  console.log("My uid - " + uid);

  // setting new value for input$uid variable
  Shiny.onInputChange("uid", uid);
  // for newer version of shiny 
  //Shiny.setInputValue("uid", uid);
  '
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  user<-reactive({

  input$goButton    
  user <- some_function_for_uid(input$uid)

  })

}
```

Problems:

1. On first load of app value of variable "uid" is not changing. The value remains as it was in textInput function (`value="1"`)
2. Server function `some_function_for_uid()` receive new value of variable **only** when I press goButton. But value in text form still remains the same.

How correctly change default value in textInput and avoid described problems?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To update the value in the `textInput`:

```
$("#uid").val(uid);
```

I don't know what you want to do with the button. Is it OK like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("uid", label = h4("Input ID"), value = "1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("showUID"),
  #actionButton("goButton", "Check this out!", class="btn-primary"),

  tags$script(HTML(
    '
    uid = "hello";

    // setting new value in the textInput
    $("#uid").val(uid);

    // setting new value for input$uid variable
    Shiny.onInputChange("uid", uid);
    '
  ))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  user <- eventReactive(input$uid, {
    rep(input$uid, 3)
  })

  output[["showUID"]] <- renderText({user()})

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This `$("#uid").val(uid);` partly helps. But I want to use button for submiting data. Reactive behavior is not convinient when calculations take a long time.

Comment: Almost good :) But I want to see result for first (default) value without pressing button, on app startup.

Comment: @Yuriy Mmhh not sure, but I would try the option `ignoreNULL=FALSE`, like this : `eventReactive(input$goButton, {......}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)`.

Comment: `ignoreNULL = FALSE` works and one can see result on app startup. But the problem is that in this case variable `uid` is **not reassigned** by js and is taken from the input form default (`value=1`). The same strange behavior I can see in my code too. Actually this is the main problem in this whole case.